# Firebase analytics event parameters not showing in console

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I have been logging my event clicks, which seem to show up but I can't seem to find parameters anywhere in the Firebase Console. All I see is:

> Events with custom reporting parameters will show up here

Here is how I am adding parameters:

```
var map = {'label': value};
_analytics.logEvent(name: 'session_button', parameters: map);
```

I can see `session_button` showing up in my console, just no data for the event parameters. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hey have u tried `_analytics.logEvent('session_button', map);`

Comment: Why would that work?

Comment: b/c you are using named params, and on their official doc, they just use it the naming. It's just something to try

Comment: @adkstar The code you posted is exactly the same as the OPs but does not correctly pass the named parameters that the official docs specify. It won't work guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have any error in your code.

In the events tab of the Firebase Analytics console you have to click the three vertical dots on the right of your `session_button` event and do `Edit parameter reporting`. From there you can add the parameter that you want. Your custom `label` parameter should be on that list assuming the event has been triggered at some point. Following this your parameters should show up in other views.

Answer (score 0):

Just Follow the below steps

If you are debugging than first enable debug mode

**For enable**

adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app **PACKAGE_NAME**

**For disable**

adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.

And finally set this method to true you will get the all logs.

Call this method `setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled`

**Reference Link:**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics#logEvent(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)